# D3 org chart export as PDF very blurry?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, export, jspdf

I want to export an D3 org chart as an PDF in A0 - which basically works, except that the image in the PDF is very blurry...

I'm using this script, it seems that changing the dpi doesn't do anything really. Any idea why it's blurry? Should I export as SVG then? Use a different approach?

I also added the code for creating an actual chart, since it seems that this is a needed information.

```
<script>
  var chart = null;
  d3.csv(
    'data.csv'
  ).then((data) => {
    chart = new d3.OrgChart()
      .nodeHeight((d) => 85 + 25)
      .nodeWidth((d) => 220 + 2)
      .childrenMargin((d) => 50)
      .compactMarginBetween((d) => 35)
      .compactMarginPair((d) => 30)
      .neighbourMargin((a, b) => 20)
      .compactMarginBetween(node => 150)
      .nodeContent(function (d, i, arr, state) {
        const color = '#FFFFFF';
        const imageDiffVert = 25 + 2;
        return `
                <div style='width:${d.width} px;height:${d.data.height} px;padding-top:${imageDiffVert - 2}px;padding-left:1px;padding-right:1px'>
                    <div style="font-family: 'Inter', sans-serif;background-color:${color};  margin-left:-1px;width:${d.width - 2}px;height:${d.data.height - imageDiffVert}px;border-radius:10px;border: 1px solid #E4E2E9">
                        <div style="display:flex;justify-content:flex-end;margin-top:5px;margin-right:8px"><br/> 
                        </div>                      
                        <div style="background-color:${color};margin-top:${-imageDiffVert - 20}px;margin-left:${15}px;border-radius:100px;width:50px;height:50px;" ></div>
                        <div style="margin-top:${-imageDiffVert - 20
          }px;">   <img src=" ${d.data.image}" style="margin-left:${20}px;border-radius:100px;width:40px;height:40px;" /></div>
                        <div style="font-size:15px;color:#08011E;margin-left:20px;margin-top:10px">  ${d.data.name
          } </div>
                        <div style="color:#716E7B;margin-left:20px;margin-top:3px;font-size:10px;"> ${d.data.position
          } </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
                            `;
      })
      .container('.chart-container')
      .data(data)
      .render();

  });
</script>

<script>
  function downloadPdf(chart) {
    var dpi = 300;

    chart.exportImg({
      save: false,
      full: true,
      pixelRatio: dpi / 300,
      onLoad: (base64) => {
        var pdf = new jspdf.jsPDF('landscape', 'mm', 'a0');
        var img = new Image();
        img.src = base64;
        img.onload = function () {
          var widthInInches = img.width / dpi;
          var heightInInches = img.height / dpi;

          var aspectRatio = img.height / img.width;

          var pdfWidth = 1189;
          var pdfHeight = pdfWidth * aspectRatio;

          pdf.addImage(
            img,
            'JPEG',
            0,
            0,
            pdfWidth,
            pdfHeight
          );
          pdf.save('chart.pdf');
        };
      },
    });
  }
</script>
```

Comment: This question is missing some information.  What is the `chart` object that's providing an `exportImg` method?  These are not base d3 things.   I also added a `jspdf` tag to your question as the question seems more pertinent to that library.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to run your code example and I can see that the problem is not from jsPDF. Next time, please provide a reproducible example that can be copied and executed without modifications, as it took me more time to run the code than to identify the issue. jsPDF adds the image to the pdf file without to compress it or to change the quality. I downloaded the image generated from exportImg method and I saw that the quality is not good. To receive image with better quality, I changed "pixelRatio: dpi / 300" to "scale: 10". I want to mention that the number 10 was the first number which came in my mind. The method exportImg do not have argument called "pixelRatio". Then I received image with better quality and it was the same quality in the pdf file.

I would touch and the function which creates the pdf, but I think this is off topic.